# Flask API with CORS error in delete method

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, cors

I have developed a rest api in Flask. All my api endpoints work fine when I test them with postman.

Now, I am developing an application with Javascript that consumes the resources of my api.

I'm having trouble consuming an endpoint that works with the delete method. Endpoints with get and post work fine, but not the delete method. I get the next CORS error:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/contacto' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
```

This is my Javascript code:

```
let data ={id: id};
let url = "http://localhost:5000/contacto";
fetch(url, {
    credentials: 'include',
    method: 'DELETE',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => {
    alert(res.result);
});
```

On the server side, I use flask_cors. I configure the app with this code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS

import controllers.userController as userController

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
#CORS(app)
#CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}}, send_wildcard=True)
 CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "http://127.0.0.1:5500"}})
```

The path of my service with delete method is this:

```
@app.route('/contacto', methods = ['DELETE'])
def deleteContacto():
  parametros = request.args
  id = parametros['id']
  result = contactController.eliminar_contacto(id)

 response = None
if result == True:
    response = jsonify({'result':'Contacto eliminado con éxito'})
else:
    response = jsonify({'result':'Error al eliminar el contacto'})
response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS')
return response
```

I need some help. I have searched and tried many possible solutions but they do not work for me. I'm a bit desperate.

Thanks in advance and regards.

Comment: Can you show the corresponding Headers for this request. I think you are missing something on the flask configuration.

Comment: You can't use the wildcard (`*`) while also allowing credentialed requests. Instead of using the wildcard, only specify your frontend's origin as the allowed origin. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards

Comment: Also, the error message indicates that you're issuing your request from the `null` origin. Do resist the temptation to allow that origin. Allowing it with credentials is quite insecure.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have made some modifications to the code with the suggestions you have given me (I have edited the original post with the changes), but I still get the same problem

Comment: @MARodriguez Has the error message changed since you stopped using the wildcard?

Comment: No. I get the same error from CORS. The problem is with the Delete service. Get services work without problem. Could it have something to do with how the data is sent to the service? This is frustating

Answer (score -1):

I do this a bit different, but make sure you have this option set to allow delete and options methods:

`'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS'`

I add them manually to the response object in flask

```
resp.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS')
```

CORS should be setting this as a default, but maybe something is misconfigured?
see the docs:
https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html